# serialize an entity that extends FOS user model

Tags: json, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a user entity that extends the entity model of FOsUserBundle (FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User), as they recommend it.

Then I'd like to get all the users I have and pass them to twig as a json:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$user_array = em->getRepository('MyBundle:user')->findByCustomer($customerID);
```

So I have an array which contains objects.

if I do:

```
json_encode($user_array);
```

or

```
json_encode($user_array[0]);
```

I get an empty string {}. I was at least expecting to get the array defined in the FOS User class

```
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->usernameCanonical,
        $this->username,
        $this->expired,
        $this->locked,
        $this->credentialsExpired,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id,
    ));
}
```

but it seems actually FOS doesn't implements Jsonserialize so it doesn't work.
When I change the FOS user class to implement Jsonserialize, it stops working (I can't connect anymore for example...).

Is there any way to get this work with FOS ?

Answer (score 0):

All fields in the FriendsOfSymfony User entity are protected.

Which means you can simply reference them in the User class that is extending it just as you would a normal field.

This also means you can add another method in your own User class that will return an json encoded array containing all the values of the User.

Example of this would be:

```
public function json_encode()
{
    return json_encode(array(
        $this->password,
        $this->salt,
        $this->usernameCanonical,
        $this->username,
        $this->expired,
        $this->locked,
        $this->credentialsExpired,
        $this->enabled,
        $this->id,
    ));
}
```

You can't just simply json encode the whole array so the way to do it is:

```
$jsonEncodedUserArray = array();

foreach($user_array as $user) {
    $jsonEncodedUser = $user->json_encode();
    array_push($jsonEncodedUserArray, $jsonEncodedUser);
}
```